# Looking for Google Sheet Array Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hello I'm trying to create a Array Formula for the following **B and C** columns but getting error,
but without Array Formula the formula works by dragging the formula to all the cells. So I need a Array Formula so I can restrict a formula for specific range, So when I add a new row anywhere in d middle the that row should be working without any formula.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kc58OkoA3SysApgALJnecnIoK2uyPV6FlhyVRTUXXcI/edit?usp=sharing

So in the above link where there is a list of items in Sheet2 A:
and I importing the list to Sheet1 A: with Array Formula.

Now in D column dropdown list whenever we select an item it keeps removing the used items from C column.

**So how to make work while adding Array Formula for B and C Column.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a complete chage of strategy ... in B1 Sheet2

```
=arrayformula(countif(Sheet1!D:D,A1:A))
```

then in C1 Sheet1 (nothing in B1 Sheet1)

```
=iferror(query(Sheet2!A:B,"select A where A is not null and B=0 "))
```

the red corner is a good indication that the item is reserved. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m_SACJtoN2k-c1p4C-eflh3pKLmv6YqP8BM2i0jDUhw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Mike Its working i updated your code in my above sheet. but when i select all the items available in drop down list C1:C5 then its showing an N/A in drop down list and in B1.

Comment: ok, replace the formula, I have updates the answer

Comment: and 1 more help if i have another formula Sheet1!A7 while importing from Sheet2!C1  then code breaks in Sheet1!A1.  Is it possible to get multiple formulas adding in every few row down in Sheet 1 without breaking the code.

Comment: you need to limit the area `=ArrayFormula(Sheet2!A1:A6)` in A1.

Comment: I tried that it will work  but when we add some lists to Sheet2! A: or C: Column then it wont be appear in Sheet1 table. So we need to add manually another row in Sheet1 to get those list.  So is there any possibility to get automatically add a row in Sheet1 when the list has been updated in Sheet2.  other than keeping few empty rows in Sheet1.

Comment: arrayformula usually needs a free column, I don't have a solution, the best is to change the layout so that you don't have any constraints

Comment: Also I need to attach a prefix text before all the list in dropdown list. I can't make changes in Sheet2! Original column so I need to add it in  anywhere in Sheet1! formula.  And what changes needs to add if I want dropdown list apears in D: colums also in sheet1.

Comment: Ok added drop down in D column but it wont remove used items and only works in c column.  also i updated my sheet and added column E,F,G with formula and my final list should be like G:Column. is it possible to combine all formula to fit in 1 formula.

Comment: So if there is any duplicates in dropdown list it will be avoid so I need to give a exact list with series number like 1 to 100 or 1000. If there is any duplicate items in list it should be needed so.

Comment: If you want to work with multiple columns, in Sheet2!B1 `=arrayformula(countif(Sheet1!C2:D6,A1:A))` then apply the prefix. I dont understand the number in column G

Comment: OK i updated my sheet, what ever the items in drop down list is a category so i need to add a category (BS) + (Series) starts from 1 to 5 if there is only 5 in drop down list. So if i combine ```E,F and G``` in a single formula the we can use G column as a drop down list. ( Prefix + Count + Items)

Comment: This subject is constantly evolving, I am stopping my contribution